# Show multiple pages at a time while ViewPager is scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` control. I have an image and many `textviews` in each page. I have used left and right padding along with `page margin` to show the next and previous pages partially while the selected page is being displayed.

I want to show multiple pages at a time while `ViewPager` is `scrolling`. Once the scroll is stopped would like to show only the selected page in the center and show the previous and next pages partially (*just like before scroll started*).

I tried to achieve this by increasing the "left" and "right" padding while `ViewPager` is `scrolling` and resetting the `padding` when the scroll is stopped. Increasing the padding is working fine, and I am able to see multiple pages at a time. But the resetting the padding to original values is not working. After the padding is reset to original values `ViewPager` is showing **unexpected alignment**.

I also tried by setting negative margin. Still resetting the margin is **not working as expected**.

Here is the `ViewPager` definition

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="160dp"/>

viewPager.setPageMargin(CAROUSEL_PAGE_MARGIN);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        if(getContext() != null) {

                            int paddingLeft = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_30dp);
                            int paddingRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_30dp);

                            int paddingTop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_20dp);
                            int paddingBottom = 0;

                            viewPager.setPaddingRelative(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
                        }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                            if (getContext() != null) {

                                int paddingLeft = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_100dp);
                                int paddingRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_100dp);

                                int paddingTop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_20dp);
                                int paddingBottom = 0;

                                viewPager.setPaddingRelative(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
                            }

                        }

                        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            if (getContext() != null) {

                                int paddingLeft = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_30dp);
                                int paddingRight = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_30dp);

                                int paddingTop = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.abstract_20dp);
                                int paddingBottom = 0;

                                viewPager.setPaddingRelative(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is what I need,

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a reference image of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I got you right, you might take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html)

Comment: You can use an animation wich zoom out all the fragments inside the viewPager when you're scrolling. https://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_page_transformer_zoomout.mp4

Comment: @nimi0112 Thanks for your reply. I just add the reference image. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You this code snippet & upvote when your issue gets resolve using this :)

```
        mViewPager.setClipChildren(false);
        mViewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
        int margin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_margin_large);//16dp
        final int padding = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.d_margin_ex_large);//18dp
        mViewPager.setPageMargin(margin);
        mViewPager.setPadding(padding * 2, 0, padding * 2, 0);
        mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    page.setTranslationX(-(padding));
                } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == mViewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                    page.setTranslationX(padding);
                } else {
                    page.setTranslationX(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!. Unfortunately its not what I am looking for. I just added an image of what I am trying to implement. Could you please check. Thanks!